# Failed to incorporate iOS SDK

Tags: xtify

XCODE 6.0.1
IBM Push Notification SDK for Apple iOS 2.7.3

I created new project(So my app is just hello world app), and I followed the steps below.

- Implement the IBM Push Notification SDK for Apple iOS within your App
  http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/Getting+Started+with+Apple+Push+Notification+Service#GettingStartedwithApplePushNotificationService-Implementthe%C2%A0IBMPushNotificationSDKforAppleiOSwithinyourApp

I added following property to info.plist.

- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

I added "-fno-objc-arc" compiler flag to below files since the ARC is valid in myproject.

- CompanyInboxViewCell.m
- CompanyCustomInbox.m
- CompanyInboxVC.m
- CompanyDetailsVC.m
- AppDelegate.m

I built it. Then I got following errors in "registerForPush method", which is in "XLXtifyOptions.m" file.
[capture is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6bJs_BD_RTHdm51cWp4OU1rbk0/view?usp=sharing)

```
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:107:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UIApplication'
UIApplication * app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:107:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'app'
UIApplication * app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
                ^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:107:28: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UIApplication'
UIApplication * app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
                       ^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:110:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'app'
if([app respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)])
    ^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:112:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UIUserNotificationType'
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
        ^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:113:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UIUserNotificationSettings'
    UIUserNotificationSettings * settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
    ^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:113:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'settings'
    UIUserNotificationSettings * settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
                                 ^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:113:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UIUserNotificationSettings'
    UIUserNotificationSettings * settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
                                             ^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:114:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'app'
    [app registerUserNotificationSettings: settings];
     ^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:115:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'app'
    [app registerForRemoteNotifications];
     ^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:120:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UIRemoteNotificationType'
    UIRemoteNotificationType types = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;
    ^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:122:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'types'
        types = UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;
        ^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:122:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability'
        types = UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;
                ^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:122:76: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge'
        types = UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;
                                                                       ^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:122:108: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound'
        types = UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;
                                                                                                       ^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:122:139: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert'
        types = UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;
                                                                                                                                      ^
/Users/username/Documents/objectiveCpractice/appname/XtifyLib/XLXtifyOptions.m:123:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'app'
    [app registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:types];
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I succeeded to build and deploy sample application. So I must miss something but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: I added "#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>" to XLXtifyOptions.m.Then errors are gone, is this correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that "#import '<'UIKit/UIKit.h'>'" is correct solution.
IBM Push Notification SDK for Apple iOS 2.7.3 was updated to 2.7.4. "XLXtifyOptions.m" of 2.7.4 version import UIKit/UIKit.h.

After that, I succeeded to build. But I got following error when I executed it.

[XLappMgr init]
    2014-11-12 13:40:38.811 XtifyApp[479:95045] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x181d9e084 0x1923d40e4 0x181d9dfc4 0x182b9d8b4 0x10004ef0c 0x10004e738 0x10003f784 0x1865864a4 0x100042608 0x192a42a08)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I added "Bundle display name" property to info.plist. Then above error is gone.

Thanks.